# How to return most repeated letter in python?

Tags: python

I've done some digging and most use arrays, but our class is not that far and we're to use mostly for loops to return the most repeated letter in a function.

Here was my code so far, but all I could get was to return the count of the first letter.

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):
  x = 0
  z = 0
  for letter in word_1:
    y = word_1.count(letter[0:])
    if y > z:
      z = y
    x += 1
    return z

print most_repeated_letters('jackaby')
```

Comment: put return statement one tab left. It ends for loop after first iteration.

Comment: Also, is x really neccesary?

Answer (score 2):

Make use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter('jackaby').most_common(1)
print(c)
# [('a', 2)]
```

Comment: I think it's clear that the person asking the question wants to do this with manual logic, not a predefined library.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- you calculate the count of the most common letter, but not the letter itself
- you `return` *inside* the loop and thus after the very first letter
- also, you never use `x`, and the slicing of `letter` is unneccesary

Some suggestions to better spot those errors yourself:

- use more meaningful variable names
- use more than two spaces for indentation

Fixing those, your code might look something like this:

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):
    most_common_count = 0
    most_common_letter = None
    for letter in word_1:
        count = word_1.count(letter)
        if count > most_common_count:
            most_common_count = count
            most_common_letter = letter
    return most_common_letter
```

---

Once you are comfortable with Python's basic language features, you should have a closer look at the [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). In fact, your entire function can be reduced to a single line using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), using the `word_1.count` as the `key` function for comparison.

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):
    return max(word_1, key=word_1.count)
```

But while this is very short, it is not very efficient, as the `count` function is called for each letter in the word, giving the function quadratic complexity *O(n²)*. Instead, you can use a `dict` to store counts of individual letters and increase those counts in a single pass over the word in O(n).

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):
    counts = {}
    for letter in word_1:
        if letter not in counts:
            counts[letter] = 1
        else:
            counts[letter] += 1
    return max(counts, key=counts.get)
```

And this is basically the same as what `collections.Counter` would do, as already described in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use the collections modue :

```
def mostRepeatedLetter(text):
  counter = {}
  for letter in text:
    if letter in counter: 
      counter[letter]+=1
    else: 
      counter[letter]=1
  max = { letter: 0, quantity: 0 } 
  for key, value in counter.items(): 
    if value > max.quantity: 
      max.letter, max.quantity = key, value
  return max
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Counter:

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):
    lettersCount = {}
    for ch in word_1:
        if ch not in lettersCount:
            lettersCount[ch] = 1
        else:
            lettersCount[ch] += 1

    return max(lettersCount, key=lettersCount.get)


print(most_repeated_letters('jackabybb'))
```

Comment: I made a similar one but it doesnt return two letters if there are two with same amount

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works for multiple:

```
def most_repeated_letters(word_1):

    d = {}

    for letter in word_1:      
        if not d.get(letter):
            d[letter] = 0
        d[letter] = d.get(letter) + 1

    ret = {}

    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if d[k] == max(d.values()):
            ret[k] = v

    return ret

most_repeated_letters('jackaby')
```